# How to set page counter or change page number in central European Journal class (CEJ)

Tags: page-numbering

I want to know How to set page counter or change page number in central European Journal class (CEJ) The document class can be download [here](https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/cej.cls). Kindly help me

Comment: I am afraid you will have to provide us with a bit more information, at least, a complete file which shows the class file you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with the usual commands.

For example, if you want `roman` page numbering, simply issue

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

while, if you want to set the page number to `9`, simply issue

```
\setcounter{page}{9}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{cej}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{9}

\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @user51868 You're welcome. Remember that you can accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)